# Why does my loop only return the last item of the loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, closures

Below, I'm using the `.each()` method to loop through the links of a navigation bar and use each link's data attribute as an argument for `myFunc`:

```
var $nav = $(".nav"),
    $navLinks = $nav.find(".nav-item");

$navItems.each(function(idx, elem) {
    var $self = $(this);

     $self.on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

       myFunc($(this).data(myAttr));
    });
});
```

My problem is that the above code only returns the last item of my loop. Even when I wrap the `$elf.on` code in an immediately-invoked function expression, it still calls the last item of my loop. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is $navItems defined?

Comment: @Cruiser - guess: `$navItems` means `$navLinks`

Comment: @Wilhelm - "above code only returns the last item of my loop" - returns where?

Comment: Your function call to myFunc() only happens inside a click event, so your loop isn't really doing anything but attaching the events to the items.

Comment: @Cruiser Except it calls `myFunc()` but only with the data attribute for the last item. I don't understand why it would do this.